# Jackrabbit restrict SNS (with nt:unstructured)

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

Is it possible in Jackrabbit to restrict same name name siblings, without fully defining the types of my nodes? I am looking (I guess) for a simple CND definition that I can apply to my repository and use as the type of all of my nodes.

I am trying to follow the guidelines here: (http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DavidsModel), specifically, #1 avoiding creating a strong schema up-front, but I find this to be incompatible with #4, avoiding same name siblings.

I can manually avoid same name siblings, by locking the relevant parent node (collection), and checking for a node with the same name manually, and I will probably do this anyway in order to present application level error messages, but I'd prefer an additional layer of protection against inconsistency.

Also, I found this document:

http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/1.0/4.3.2_Support_for_Same_Name_Siblings_is_Optional.html

> Though there is a required set of node types that every compliant repository must support, **none of these required node types allow same-name siblings** and any further node types available in a particular repository are implementation-specific. Therefore, it is possible for a repository to disallow same-name siblings altogether by restricting the set of available node types.

This seems inconsistent with what I have observed, e.g.:

```
final Repository repository = new TransientRepository();
final Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("username", "password".toCharArray()));
final Node collection = session.getRootNode().addNode("collection", "nt:unstructured");
final Node childA = collection.addNode("child", "nt:unstructured");
final Node childB = collection.addNode("child", "nt:unstructured");
session.save();
System.err.println(collection.getNodes("child").getSize());
//prints 2
```

Is this something that's changed in version 2.0 of JCR? (I notice that is a v1.0 specification)

I find JCR seems very appropriate in principle, but the lack of documentation is letting it down for me at the moment, so any links to good up-to-date information would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the CND definition for nt:unstructured here:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/Defining+custom+node+types

I came up with this definition:

```
<my = 'http://example.com/my'>
[my:unstructured] orderable
  - * (undefined) multiple
  - * (undefined)
  + * (nt:base) = my:unstructured version
```

This seems to be working, now I get this on the attempt to add the second child node:

> javax.jcr.ItemExistsException: This node already exists: /collection/child
>     at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.addNode(NodeImpl.java:1508)
>     at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.addNodeWithUuid(NodeImpl.java:2087)
>     at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.addNode(NodeImpl.java:1992)

Which is what I expected.